# ASP. net core localization with resoucrce data in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, localization

I have an asp.net webforms application which is being upgraded to asp.net core mvc.
The current webforms application supports localization and all the resource data is in 
database tables. I am working on localization for mvc app and want to reuse my database
to store the localization resource file information.

**Loalization.sqlLocalizer**  (nuget package ) https://localizationsqllocalizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  from my understanding is that it needs to use the database structure defined by the package and is not customizable.

What are my other options or pointers which I can look at to implement this in MVC?

Comment: check [this tool](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/index.md), it offers db, xml, etc based localization with online translation support and auto resource creating.

Comment: Hi, I am in the same place as you were. I am curious to know how did you proceed in implementing localisation?

Comment: I have developed a solution including resource strings in database, a dashboard and some unique features. Download / read about it on:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5348357/Localizing-ASP-NET-Core-MVC-Applications-from-Data

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to store your languages and string resources in database.

- **Languages** table can have Id, Name and Culture columns.
- **StringResources** table can have Id, Name, Value and LanguageId columns.

Next, generate the EF Core entities related to these database tables.

Here is an example of Language entity

```
public partial class Language
{
    public Language()
    {
        StringResources = new HashSet<StringResource>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StringResource> StringResources { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of StringResource entity

```
public partial class StringResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

Next, implement few services to fetch languages and string resources from database. Here is an example of LanguageService

```
public class LanguageService : ILanguageService
{
    private readonly MyAppDbContext _context;

    public LanguageService(MyAppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Language> GetLanguages()
    {
        return _context.Languages.ToList();
    }

    public Language GetLanguageByCulture(string culture)
    {
       return _context.Languages.FirstOrDefault(x => 
           x.Culture.Trim().ToLower() == culture.Trim().ToLower());
    } 
}
```

Here is an example of a LocalizationService that has a method to return StringResource from database using the resource key.

```
public class LocalizationService : ILocalizationService
{
    private readonly MyAppDbContext _context;

    public LocalizationService(MyAppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public StringResource GetStringResource(string resourceKey, int languageId)
    {
        return _context.StringResources.FirstOrDefault(x => 
            x.Name.Trim().ToLower() == resourceKey.Trim().ToLower() 
            && x.LanguageId == languageId);
    }
}
```

Next step is to configure ASP.NET Core Localization according to the guidelines available in official Microsoft docs. Once everything is setup, you can create a method e.g. Localize to read localized strings. To use this method in multiple Controllers, this method can be defined in a BaseController class.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILanguageService _languageService;
    private readonly ILocalizationService _localizationService;

    public BaseController(ILanguageService languageService, ILocalizationService localizationService)
    {
        _languageService = languageService;
        _localizationService = localizationService;
    }

    public HtmlString Localize(string resourceKey, params object[] args)
    {
        var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;

        var language = _languageService.GetLanguageByCulture(currentCulture);
        if (language != null)
        {
            var stringResource = _localizationService.GetStringResource(resourceKey, language.Id);
            if (stringResource == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringResource.Value))
            {
                return new HtmlString(resourceKey);
            }

            return new HtmlString((args == null || args.Length == 0)
                ? stringResource.Value
                : string.Format(stringResource.Value, args));
        }

        return new HtmlString(resourceKey);
    }
}
```

Using this Localize method, reading localized strings is as easy as the following example.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Title"] = Localize("customer.page.create.title");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Waqas. Just what i was looking for

Comment: Will you please specify the startup configuration for this?